# how to compile with protocol buffer into .so file

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to use Google's Protocol buffer on a C++ project. I can build it just fine for say... an iOS framework target. However, I can't seem to get the compiler to find any of the google/protobuf files. I already have the static library file (not sure if this one works on my architecture? i used: https://gist.github.com/BennettSmith/9487468ae3375d0db0cc)

in the output of the proto file, let's say `blah.pb.h`, i have a reference to protobuf:

`#include <google/protobuf/stubs/common.h>`

the compiler can't find that ^ reference.

I've tried to `ndk-build` with something like this:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libprotobuf
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := src/lib/libprotobuf.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES:=$(shell find src/lib -name '*.cpp')
LOCAL_MODULE := mymodule
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += ./src/lib

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libprotobuf
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

but it doesn't seem to help at all. what's going on? how do i include lib protobuf when i have the .a file? do i have to compile it from source?

Comment: path to include(folder) that contains google/protobuf/stubs/common.h whould be included in build file (IIRC something with LOCAL_C_INCLUDES)

Comment: @Selvin any ideas on how exactly to do that?

Comment: @Selvin code updated. but still doesn't work. i do use LOCAL_C_INCLUDES and the .a file is in `src/lib`

Answer (score 0):

turns out i have to multiple things:

i have to duplicate the entire protobuf `include` folder (the one with all the headers) to my project. and then include them in my `LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES`

also, the command that i was using to do ndk-build is also not fully correct. it was missing a ton of stl stuff, like missing "string" or `vector` or `map`. so i used this instead:

```
ndk-build V=1 NDK_PROJECT_PATH=. APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=Android.mk APP_STL=stlport_static
```

[NDK - Android Java with native (JNI) C++ code build issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107104/ndk-android-java-with-native-jni-c-code-build-issue)